# Specifying default parameters C++

Tags: c++, arguments, default-arguments

I have written the following class

```
class worker
{
   int action;
   int doJob(int type,int time = 0);
   public:
   int call();
}
```

And the function doJob is like

```
int worker::doJob(int type,int time = 0)
{
          ....code here
}
```

When i compile ,i am getting the following error

```
 error: the default argument for parameter 1 of 'int worker::doJob(int, int)' has not yet been parsed
```

Surely it is a problem with default parameter specification..So what is the problem with th e prototype?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to redefine the default value

`int worker::doJob(int type,int time = 0)`

can just be

`int worker::doJob(int type,int time)`

As you do not need to define the argument more than once.

Comment: I take issue with "you don't need" and "can just be" above. You _can't_ redefine the default value, and the first line _must_ be changed to second line.

Answer (score 4):

Put the default in the declaration (ie inside `class worker` in your example), but not in the definition, e.g. code simply:

```
 int worker::doJob(int type,int time)
 {  /* your code here */ }
```

Answer (score 1):

`int worker::doJob(int type,int time = 0)` is giving you an error, you should only declare your default argument once.